# Magento 2 Remote Database connection?

Tags: magento2

`Mysql` using 80% `cpu` power. It's causes server down. so we're planning to move our `mysql` to another server. Searched on google but did not found any good results. Can you guys please explain what should we do? or how to connect with a remote database?
Thank you in advance

Comment: what exactly were you looking for in google ???

Comment: thank you for replying. here is the query how to connect remote mysql database in magento 2

Comment: I think initially you should use blackfire or new relic to profile your website. This will give you a better idea on what's happening and what's causing load. You might be able to make code changes to improve performance. Have you used mysql tuner?

Answer (score 1):

install mysql on another sever. if you have private network then use it to bind mysql server and connection between servers, if not, so you can configure firewall.

create the same mysql user for magento database with proper host and access rights.
create magento database.
stop nginx/apache server and disable cronjobs.
take magento database dump.

```
mysqldump --single-transaction --routines --triggers --events magento | gzip > magento.sql.gz
```

copy database dump to your mysql server.

import your database:

```
zcat magento.sql.gz | mysql -f magento
```

after import:

```
mysql_upgrade -f
service mysql restart
```

you have `env.php` file with all configuration. change `localhost` to `REMOTE_IP_ADDRESS`

```
'db' => [
        'table_prefix' => '',
        'connection' => [
            'default' => [
                'host' => 'REMOTE_IP_ADDRESS',
                'dbname' => 'XXX',
                'username' => 'XXX',
                'password' => 'XXX',
                'model' => 'mysql4',
                'engine' => 'innodb',
                'initStatements' => 'SET NAMES utf8;',
                'active' => '1'
            ]
        ]
    ],
```

Comment: are you sure this will help us?

Comment: your question was about - `how to connect with a remote database`